# Which directory do I run java -jar my-webapp-0.1.0-standalone.jar?

Tags: java, jar, clojure, leiningen, ring

In [this tutorial](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/tutorials/basic_web_development.html#build-and-run-it) it says

> Now create an uberjar of your webapp (`via lein uberjar`), copy it
>   (`target/my-webapp-0.1.0-standalone.jar`) to wherever you like, and
>   run it in the usual way:
>
> `java -jar my-webapp-0.1.0-standalone.jar 8080`

I run it from its own directory `~/myapp/target/` but I get an error:

> target $ java -jar my-webapp-0.1.0-standalone.jar
>
> no main manifest attribute, in my-webapp-0.1.0-standalone.jar

`-main` function is already in handler.clj:

```
(ns my-webapp.handler
  (:require [my-webapp.views :as views]
            [compojure.core :as cc]
            [compojure.handler :as handler]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty]
            (:gen-class)))

(cc/defroutes app-routes
  (cc/GET "/"
       []
       (views/home-page))
  (cc/GET "/add-location"
       []
       (views/add-location-page))
  (cc/POST "/add-location"
        {params :params}
        (views/add-location-results-page params))
  (cc/GET "/location/:loc-id"
       [loc-id]
       (views/location-page loc-id))
  (cc/GET "/all-locations"
       []
       (views/all-locations-page))
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (handler/site app-routes))

(defn -main
  [& [port]]
  (let [port (Integer. (or port
                           (System/getenv "PORT")
                           5000))]
    (jetty/run-jetty #'app {:port  port
                            :join? false})))
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

---

**EDIT**

I am adding my `project.clj`:

```
(defproject my-webapp "0.1.0"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [hiccup "1.0.2"]
                 [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.2.3"]
                 [com.h2database/h2 "1.3.170"]
                 [compojure "1.1.6"]
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.2.1"]]
  :main my-webapp.handler
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.8"]]
  :ring {:handler my-webapp.handler/app}
  :profiles
  {:dev {:dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
                        [ring-mock "0.1.5"]
                        [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.0.4"] ]}})
```

and `handler.clj`

```
    (ns my-webapp.handler
  (:require [my-webapp.views :as views]
            [compojure.core :as cc]
            [compojure.handler :as handler]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty])
  (:gen-class))

(cc/defroutes app-routes
  (cc/GET "/"
       []
       (views/home-page))
  (cc/GET "/add-location"
       []
       (views/add-location-page))
  (cc/POST "/add-location"
        {params :params}
        (views/add-location-results-page params))
  (cc/GET "/location/:loc-id"
       [loc-id]
       (views/location-page loc-id))
  (cc/GET "/all-locations"
       []
       (views/all-locations-page))
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (handler/site app-routes))

(defn -main
  [& [port]]
  (let [port (Integer. (or port
                           (System/getenv "PORT")
                           5000))]
    (jetty/run-jetty #'app {:port  port
                            :join? false})))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you do this step in the [deploy your webapp section](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/tutorials/basic_web_development.html#deploy-your-webapp)

- and also add :main my-webapp.handler

If this doesn't help then could you post the entire project.clj file so we can look for other problems?

Comment: You are right, I missed that line, `:main my-webapp.handler`. But after adding it I get this error: `$ java -jar my-webapp.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class my_webapp.handler`. I copied `my-webapp-0.1.0-standalone.jar` to `~/my-webapp/my-webapp.jar` and ran `java -jar my-webapp.jar` from `~/my-webapp`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ok, I think it is working now. I changed the place of `(:gen-class)` but I did not realize that I had to run `lein uberjar` again. Correct? I'll make another change on the layout of the page and try again.

Comment: Can you help me with deployment too? I asked several questions already but I still do not understand how I can deploy with nginx and ring. How do I add nginx to this setup without creating war and without using jetty? Is that possible? Should I use immutant?

Comment: In practice deploying a war file to an application server (like tomcat or immutant) or running a jar which starts it's own webserver are the normal options. Typically Nginx is run infront of these to proxy the connections to the jetty server running out of the jar.